# Vue router is safe?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, console, vue-router

i'm developing a web with vue and i realize that if i put this in console

```js
document.getElementById('app').__vue__.$router.push("some_route")
```

it works despite of the meta that i declare in **beforeEach** navigation guard (requireAuth).
I need to make some routes that some random user can't access, in the api made in flask i return a token and a role, this works fine if i try to access throug the adress bar in any navigator but when i access through console it doesn't, the router push the route withouth do the authentication.

```
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)){
    let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')) //user is a json with a jwt token

    if (user && user.token){
      
      await user_service.isLogged(to.path).then(response => {
       //wait for a response from the server if the token is valid
        switch (response.status){
          case 200:
            next()
            break;

          case 401:
            next({path: '/login'})
            break;
          
          case 403:
            next({path: '/403'})
            break;
        }
      })
    }else{
      next({path: '/login'})
    }

  }
  next()
})
```

**i appreciate any feedback. Thanks!**

Comment: If that actually does work, then you probably have a problem with your navigation guard. Can't help you with that if you don't show the code though

Comment: Yes! maybe is that, i find it strange that if i try to access the route like a normal user, using buttons or changing the url in the adress bar it works fine!

Comment: updated, thanks for your early answer

Comment: Can you show an example of your route meta properties for both authenticated and non-authenticated routes

Comment: Could you provide a working example? (use codesandbox.io).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nothing is stopping that final `next()` from running which makes your entire navigation guard redundant.

Either wrap it in an `else` block, eg

```js
if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
  // your code
} else {
  next()
}
```

or change your code to exit (via `return`) at the appropriate spots

```js
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)){
    let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))

    if (user && user.token){
      await user_service.isLogged(to.path).then(response => {
       //wait for a response from the server if the token is valid
        switch (response.status){
          case 200:
            return next()
          case 403:
            return next({path: '/403'})
          case 401:
          default:
            return next({path: '/login'})
        }
      })
    } else {
      return next({path: '/login'})
    }
  }
  next()
})
```

Comment: Given this answer has already been accepted by OP, if you downvote could you please leave a comment as to **why** exactly

Comment: i'm new in Stack overflow and i upvoted but it doesn't change the score maybe you can help me with that too. By the way i'm from Argentina and my English is pretty basic

Comment: @Lucas not you mate. Somebody came along after you accepted my answer and gave it a downvote without saying why. Makes it hard to improve my answer if I don't know what is wrong with it